# flex plugin on eclipse

Tags: adobe, eclipse, flash, adobe-air

This is not a programming question but i wanted to know How to install flex development plugin tools for eclipse on ubuntu.Point me to any links for this.Eclipse is already installed.Thanks...

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069588/flex-plugin-on-eclipse).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing programming tools. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069588/flex-plugin-on-eclipse) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex plugin has been discontinued and is no longer supported/available.

Flash Builder has now replaced Flex, but it is [not available](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/) on Linux.